# Shuffle giving same order

Tags: python, random, shuffle

When I shuffle several sublists they come out in the same order.  I'm sure I can reseed it with a random number each time, but everything I read implies that I shouldn't have to.
Code:

```
test=[list(range(10))]*5
import random
for x in test:
    random.shuffle(x)

print(test)
```

Results:

```
[[0, 8, 9, 6, 1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 3], [0, 8, 9, 6, 1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 3], [0, 8, 9, 6, 1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 3], [0, 8, 9, 6, 1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 3], [0, 8, 9, 6, 1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 3]]
```

Why isn't shuffle producing different orders?

Comment: Yep, had just realized this myself.  That's definitely it.

Comment: When you do: `test=[list(range(10))]*5` you're creating 5 references to the **same** list - the dupe above linked by @Peter explains this fairly well

Comment: I'd probably doing what you're doing go for something like define the candidate space - eg: `r = range(10)` (convenient as it can compute on the fly and doesn't really occupy space and can be re-used), and then build it up something like: `test = [random.sample(r, len(r)) for _ in range(5)]`

Answer (score 3):

It's not about shuffling, it's about the way you define the list.

```
>>> test=[list(range(3))]*2
>>> test
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
>>> test[0][0]=111
>>> test
[[111, 1, 2], [111, 1, 2]]
```

So, in practice you are shuffling the same list at each time since they all reference the same list.